# App crashing on attempt to add values of arraylist

Tags: java, android

In my activity I want the average user submitted ratings to display in a ratingbar.

The user ratings get called and I then populate an ArrayList with the values.

This part of the code works, for instance: I can `setRating(array_list.get(index))`, and the correct rating displays.

I extract the data in a thread and then try to set the rating in the following handler :

```
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
    public void run () {                

        if (t.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {

            int sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i == products.size(); i++)
            {
                sum = sum + products.get(i); //line 256
            }               
            int x = Math.round(sum / products.size());

            ratingbar1.setRating(x);

            return;
        } else {
            h.postDelayed(this, 1000);  
        }
    }
    }
, 1000);
```

The app crashes when opening and I get the following error in the logCat:

```
10-27 00:06:31.209: E/AndroidRuntime(859): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 00:06:31.209: E/AndroidRuntime(859): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 15, size is 15
10-27 00:06:31.209: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
10-27 00:06:31.209: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
10-27 00:06:31.209: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at com.example.hikebuddy.Lion$6.run(Lion.java:256)
```

I have tried playing around with this, but can't seem to think any more.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this

```
        for(int i = 0; i == products.size(); i++)
        {
            sum = sum + products.get(i); //line 256
        }
```

with this

```
        for(int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++)
        {
            sum = sum + products.get(i); //line 256
        }
```

products.size() is 15 but an array starts from 0 so last index is 14

Comment: Oh my word. Thank you. :)